# Add new service to existing supervisord process

Tags: supervisord

Say I already have a supervisord process running on my machine. How can I add a new service/process for supervisord to monitor? For example, assume I have this simple .conf file:

#### run-suman-daemon.conf

```
[program:suman-daemon]
command=/Users/alexamil/WebstormProjects/suman/cli/suman-daemon.sh
```

I tried:

```
supervisord add run-suman-daemon.conf
```

but I get this error:

```
Error: positional arguments are not supported: ['add', 'sup.conf']
For help, use /usr/local/bin/supervisord -h
```

The `supervisord` daemon is running and I can connect to it with `supervisorctl`

Comment: In other words, if I start `supervisord` with `[include]` pointing to my `sup.conf` file, then it will work. But if `supervisord` is started without including sup.conf, then I cannot find a way to point `supervisord` to sup.conf, after the fact.

Answer (score 36):

You can use following commands for reading the new configuration and starting the new processes

```
supervisorctl reread
supervisorctl update
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add a process dynamically, add this section to your `supervisord.conf`:

```
[include]
files = dir-with-your-conf-files/*.conf
```

All `conf` files placed in `dir-with-your-conf-files` will be loaded by the main config files. So you put, remove, change files in that dir (for example create symbolic links) and then run:

```
# reread configuration
supervisorctl reread
# start/stop new/old processes
supervisorctl update
```

Comment: An edit was suggesting to remove `supervisorctl reread`. I don't know if the latest version of supervisor rereads the conf when doing `update`, but this answer suggests `reread` is required: https://serverfault.com/a/479754

Answer (score 3):

I think you should call `supervisorctl update` first.